# How To Show a Toast Notification like Windows Phone in Android?

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, android-notifications, toast, android-toast

**NOT TO CONFUSE THE QUESTION as "How to Show a Toast Notification in WINDOWS PHONE like Android" and mark it as Duplicate .**

I want to Show the Message **For Exiting The Application** Using Toast in Android , I know how to Generate Basic Toast , but i would like to Generate it like Windows Phone something like below [image: Toast Notification in Windows Phone]

For Exiting the App I think Finish () will be enough inside ToastClick Method ?

Comment: I tried searching it but no links found

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to show toasts in this form. You could create a custom layout and then show it for some seconds.

To accomplish this, you should use [runnable](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) and [handler](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Comment: Thanks :) Done using this method only :)